# In JSON-LD, is it possible to extend a context?

Tags: semantic-web, linked-data, json-ld

I have a JSON-LD document.

```
{
  "@id": "VDWW1LL3MZ",
  "first_name": "Vincent",
  "last_name": "Willems",
  "knows":["MartyP"],
  "@context": {
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "first_name": "foaf:givenName",
    "last_name": "foaf:familyName",
    "knows": "foaf:knows",
    "MartyP": { 
      "@id": "http://example.com/martyp",
      "first_name": "Marty",
      "last_name": "P"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, part of the context of this document is generated in run-time (the `Marty P` object), but the `foaf` prefix definition is static, and repeated for each document.

If I have like 10 prefix definitions, it feel wasteful to put them in each and every document. So I would like to do something like

`generated document`:

```
{
  "@id": "VDWW1LL3MZ",
  "first_name": "Vincent",
  "last_name": "Willems",
  "knows":["MartyP"],
  "@context": {
    "@extends": "http://example.com/base_context.jsonld",
    "MartyP": { 
      "@id": "http://example.com/martyp",
      "first_name": "Marty",
      "last_name": "P"
    }
  }
}
```

`base_context.jsonld`:

```
  {
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "first_name": "foaf:givenName",
    "last_name": "foaf:familyName",
    "knows": "foaf:knows"
  }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: By the way, the `MartyP` resource should not be inside the @context. The context serves only to translate JSON keys and values to URIs. Instead the `MartyP` object should be whole inside the `knows` array. Please do experiment with the [JSON-LD playgroud](http://json-ld.org/playground/) to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `@context` can actually be multiple objects (or URLs), which are then combined in the order that they appear (so that it is possible to change meaning of terms - **caution there**).

To do that you use an array, where you can mix local and external contexts. Here's your example

```
{
  "@context": 
  [
    "http://example.com/base_context.jsonld",
    {
      "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's described in [section 6.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#advanced-context-usage) of JSON-LD specs.